# Men are burdened in Islam

Tags: women, men, men-women

Why is it that women are assured 100% rights and security in Islam. Whereas men are literally made into mules who are just supposed to work in order to please women and children?

Comment: You think so? The ladies think the opposite. The lesson of the story is, that humankind is never thankful of what it has, and always wants more.

Answer (score 0):

Mules usually have no say in any matter, whereas men are kings of their own castles (homes) with the right to be obeyed by their wives and children. Since a man has the right to be obeyed by them... they are under his wing and the **least** he can do is provide for them and ensure their security.

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) [said](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/20/1): Each of you is a shepherd and each of you is responsible for his flock. The amir (ruler) who is over the people is a shepherd and is responsible for his flock; a man is a shepherd in charge of the inhabitants of his household and he is responsible for his flock; a woman is a shepherdess in charge of her husband's house and children and she is responsible for them; and a man's slave is a shepherd in charge of his master's property and he is responsible for it. So each of you is a shepherd and each of you is responsible for his flock.

Moreover, women and children are the "weak ones" among the Ummah. The weak should be supported by and looked after by the strong, a basic Islamic moral. Their rights should be upheld. Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) [said](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/33/22), "O Allah, bear witness that I have issued a warning concerning (failure to fulfill) the rights of the two weak ones: Orphans and women".

The alternative is... don't get married, don't have kids. Then you can spend your life alone with no responsibilities and in turn have no one to either look after you through life or to pray for you after you pass away. -- The point being, it is to a man's own advantage to have and take care of women and children. And let's not pretend males don't love women and children.. a fact even [acknowledged](https://quran.com/3/14) in the Qur'an. The "pleasing" is mutual.

Comment: Its easier said than done. Why would a man want to sacrifice his life for 9 months worth sexual pleasure and lifetime worth stress. There are so many alternatives in the 21st century. One can always engage in other halal activities to kill time. Such as traveling etc. Marriage is actually outdating now.

Comment: We're not in the dunya to "kill time". Men have been following the sunnah of marriage for centuries and will continue to do so.. inshaAllah. It's another subject matter if it doesn't suit you personally.

Comment: Yes it doesn't suit my personality. And yes I have desires but I also have tremendous control. So I see no point in getting married. Would that count as a sin?

Comment: No, it won't count as a sin... just repent over calling it outdated though.

Comment: Well women have to sacrifice 9 months of their life too then. Men aren’t miles nor are women weak but each have their own rights and roles. Men aren’t slaves to women and vice versa. You just have responsibilities that women may not, not to mention it isn’t haram for women to work either it is just better for the man to work.

Answer (score -1):

> Why is it that women are assured 100% rights and security in Islam. Whereas men are literally made into mules who are just supposed to work in order to please women and children?

This isn't what the Qu'ran itself says:

> "They (your wives) are your garment and you are a garment for them"
>
> *Quran 2:187)*

Thus the intention is a kind of egalitarianism (whilst taking note of their basic differences).

Answer (score -3):

Clearly raising a child a making a house cannot be compared to what a man does. A man earns money, which is the basis of everything that happens in the matrimony.

Comment: Yeah it is mostly easier to earn money in fact all the bad jobs are badly paid nowadays. As a wife is practically a slave in her husband's house she's among the cheapest workers. Please consider opening your eyes and have more respect for women, your mother certainly is/was one.